# How do I parse a JSON string in Golang?

Tags: json, parsing, url, go

Given a URL like the following.

```
http://127.0.0.1:3001/find?field=hostname&field=App&filters=["hostname":"example.com,"type":"vm"]
```

How do I extract JSON values corresponding to keys for eg: hostname 'example.com' and type 'vm'.

I am trying

```
filters := r.URL.Query()["filters"]
```

which gives following output:

```
[["hostname":"example.com,"type":"vm"]]
```

Comment: Instead of trying to directly access the map from key to values diirectly, you probably mean to use `Request.FormValue` instead.  http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue

Answer (score 4):

Use the [encoding/json](http://godoc.org/encoding/json) package to parse JSON. The query string in the example URL does not contain valid JSON.

Here's an example show how to use the JSON parser on a slightly different URL.

```
s := `http://127.0.0.1:3001/find?field=hostname&field=App&filters={"hostname":"example.com","type":"vm"}`
u, err := url.Parse(s)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
var v map[string]string
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(u.Query().Get("filters")), &v)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(v)
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/wJM1d1js6a)

Comment: The example "string" the question presents isn't even a string, technically.  By using `r.URL.Query()`, they have a value of type `map[string][]string` (http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values).  So what the question is presenting isn't technically accurate: they're should be getting back a list with a single string.  They probably did a simple `fmt.Println(filters)` on the value, rather than an output statement that presents more literal output, such as `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", filters)`.